# How to display special non-ASCII Unicode characters in Notepad++? (regardless if file saved and reopened)

Tags: notepad++, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, non-ascii

When bookmarking a URL like:

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/youcare-search/

You get this bookmark title:

`YouCare - The charitable search engine – Get this Extension for  Firefox`

Then, if you copy and paste that URL title into Notepad++, the non-ASCII Unicode character (a fox, in this example), gets displayed as a box (a rectangle, to be specific).

How do you configure Notepad++ to show non-ASCII Unicode characters like this?

---

Note: This questions is related, but different than [Notepad++ special Unicode characters not displaying properly](https://superuser.com/questions/1591379/notepad-special-unicode-characters-not-displaying-properly)

That question deals with what is likely a bug in Notepad++ that causes the characters to be displayed differently after the file is saved and reopened.  ***This*** question deals with characters that do not even appear correctly when pasted into Notepad++.

---

Update:

I tried saving the above title string as a text file in Notepad++ and then reopened it.  No change.  I then tried copying the text from Notepad++ into StackExchange (in Firefox), and the text displays correctly in Firefox.

That means Notepad++ is storing the character correctly, but not displaying it as desired.

Using a hex editor, I see the fox character is being encoded as: `F0 9F A6 8A`, which is as it should be: https://www.unicode-search.net/unicode-namesearch.pl?term=fox%20face

Answer (score 1):

While my fox is grey, instead of red, it works for me. I don't have anything special installed. The only setting that I can think that may be different is `Encoding -> UTF-8`

Check to see if your setting is set to UTF-8 instead of ANSI?

[image]

> **MISC. Settings**
> [image]

> **New Document Settings**
> [image]

Comment: Thank you for trying it, DrZoo.  And thank you for your screenshot. Notepad++ is selecting UTF-8 for me as well, but displaying very differently.  Which font at are you using, and what Notepad++ version, Notepad++ bit-depth (32 or 64) and OS are you using?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I'm using Notepad++ v7.9 (64-bit) (build time Sep 22 2020 - 03:19:04) on Windows 10. Where do you find the font style? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Thanks.  In Notepad++, you can go to `Settings` > `Style Configurator...` to see the fonts.  Note that there can be fonts defined for every file type as well as a global override!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Global Styles and Global override, Courier New font. My file extension for my picture is .txt

Comment: Curious.  I tried the `Courier New` font, and even saved the text as a `.txt` file.  I still just get a rectangle where the fox should be displayed.  I'm using the same version of Notepad++ as you, although I am using the 32-bit release of it.  The only other difference I can think of is that I'm trying it on a Win7 box.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket can you try `Settings > Preferences > New Document > Encoding > UTF-8 > Apply to opened ANSI files` check marked?

Comment: I do have that already set as you recommended.  Under `Settings` > `Preferences` > `MISC.` (horrible name!), do you have `Autodetect character encoding` and `Use DirectWrite` checked or unchecked?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I added some new pics of my settings for MISC. and New Document for you to compare.

Comment: Thanks. I set up everything like you, and I get a different result. That leads me to think one (or more) of the following is the culprit: (1) a different `Courier New` font version (2) a difference between Win10 and Win7 (3) a difference between the 32-bit and 64-bit releases of Notepad++ (4) something we aren't thinking of!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket interesting. I found a post on the [Notepad++ Community](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/19164/encoding-says-file-is-utf8-but-it-s-not) that seems to be similar to your issue. I didn't get a chance to read through a lot and check the settings. Maybe see if anything from it helps you out. Otherwise could you use the 64 bit install instead?

Comment: Thank you. I'll read that post. I'll also take a look at the 64-bit Notepad++ version and see if the plugins I use are compatible with it.  Even if they aren't, I'll likely give it a try to see if it solves the issue. I have a hunch it is something else though... perhaps the font itself.  I'm trying to figure out from where Windows gets all those Unicode characters... are they simply in the corresponding installed font file, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DrZoo's answer, there is a **second possibility** of where the error comes from: Your curent font does not have a glyph for the fox. Especially since Emojis are new-ish and low on the priority of font-makers, it is quite likely that your font simply cannot provide  a symbol, in which case notepad++ defaults to the square  you see.

Check what font you have and then verify that it indeed has emojis, or switch to a font known for having them. One of these would be "consolas", which is used here on stackexchange (and given that you do have the fox in your post, we know that it includes the symbol you need)